# Change color of a certain word in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I just want to change color of some word in my Label's string.

What I want to do is:

[image: What I want to do is:]

How Im trying to do:
[image]

But it doesnt work and it says: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'

So I need an advice to do this easy thing, and I need a trick to do this. You guys can send your way.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. You can't search or reference code from an image.

Comment: @maddy my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this, your attributed string has no value when you try get the range of the string. You got to give the attributed string a string value before that. You

```
  let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {

      let label = UILabel()

      // String variable containing the text.
      let fullString = "mehmet alper tabak"

      // Choose wwhat you want to be colored.
      let coloredString = "alper"

      // Get the range of the colored string.
      let rangeOfColoredString = (fullString as NSString).range(of: coloredString)

      // Create the attributedString.
      let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:fullString)
      attributedString.setAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red],
                              range: rangeOfColoredString)
      label.attributedText = attributedString
     return label
   }()

   descriptionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 140, height: 100)
   self.view.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
```

Or you can do an extension of UILabel.

```
  extension UILabel {

      func colorString(text: String?, coloredText: String?, color: UIColor? = .red) {

      let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text!)
      let range = (text! as NSString).range(of: coloredText!)
      attributedString.setAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color!],
                               range: range)
      self.attributedText = attributedString
  }
```

To use it.

```
      self.testLabel.colorString(text: "mehmet alper tabak",
                           coloredText: "alper")
```

Comment: Thank you, thats it. Now ive got no problem, and any question marks in my mind ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It is out of bounds because `myMutableString` is empty at the time that you are trying to set attributes.  Try instead:

```
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: label.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked! But I wonder do you have another solutions? Except my way?

Comment: And what it would be a static thing, like "Welcome @username". In this case its length wouldnt be spesific.

Comment: create attributed string `let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: username, attributes: attributed)`, append to mutable `myMutableString.append(attributedString)`

Comment: @JožeWs what should I do if I want to choose a word without location and length. My label is: "robert plant with queen" and I just want to choose "robert plant" and change its color?

Comment: check out my answer, it is the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Create `attributedString1` with first color

```
let attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "robert plant ", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color1])
```

Create `attributedString2` with second color

```
let attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "with queen", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color2])
```

Add them to `myMutableString`

```
myMutableString.append(attributedString1)
myMutableString.append(attributedString1)
```